# Kendo Combobox alternative for mobile view (or any control like jQuery Mobile custom select with filter)

Tags: jquery-mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am facing problem with Kendo Combobox control for mobile view. If I focus it; then it brings virtual keyboard and combobox data goes down. It makes problem for mobile view only.

Please consider following control form jQuery mobile
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/

It is perfect for mobile view. It brings new window; from where user can choose data. Is there any equivalent control in Kendo which fits with mobile view?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a [Kendo DropDownList](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/overview)?

Comment: @Suny Patel, No. In kendo dropdown list we cannot search. There we can only select. I need something, form where i can search and select and also works with phone.

Comment: You could alternatively just have a regular text box that acts as a filter to an actual list of items, instead of combining both into a single widget. An idea could be to use the Kendo Autocomplete, and use CSS to make the suggested items list always visible.